# uploadify response with coldfsuion

Tags: jquery, response, uploadify

I am trying to use uploadify with coldfusion, the problem i am having is with my response.
My upload2.cfm file is simply hello. So I should in theory just get 'hello' in my  #newsImageHolder div. What I do get is the whole html of the current page.

Thanks for any help.

R.

```
 <script>

 $(document).ready(function() { 


 $('#newsImage').uploadify({ 
  'uploader':  '../uploadify/uploadify.swf', 
  'script':    'upload2.cfm', 
  'wmode': 'transparent',
  'auto': 'true',
  'width': '100',
  'folder':    '/', 
  'cancelImg': 'cancel.png',
  'onComplete' :
      function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {

            $('div#newsImageHolder').html(response);


      }

}); 
}); 


 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `'script':    'upload2.cfm',` definitely pointing to the right script?

Is there any chance it should be `'script':    '/upload2.cfm',`?

Comment: should this script be relative to the uploadify swf or the index page?